# python socket.connect timeout

Tags: python, sockets, irc

i've got some problem with connecting to irc server. Yesterday code attached below worked fine, but today i got error.

```
print('Script started')
network = 'irc.quakenet.org'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.settimeout(180.0)
print(irc.gettimeout())
**irc.connect((network, port))**
```

In the log i get this:

> Script started
>   180.0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users...\TM_bot1\src\connectBot.py", line 66,
>   in 
>       irc.connect((network, port)) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] [ErrMsg]

In code line which returns error is bolded.

My question is, is it a real issue with server availability? With mIRC agent i've no problems to connect to the same server and port.

**Answears for posted below questions:
It's not connected to proxy. As mentioned before - yesterday everything was working ok, and since then i haven't changed anything. 
I get this error before 180 seconds.

Now, after few hours - script is working ok, so it seems to be server overload issue. Is there any way to extend timeout?

Comment: The firewall may block you. Did you check that?

Comment: Do you get that error immediately after your socket tries to connect to the server? Or it still waits 180 secs?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the timeout setting with socket. I found this

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576655-wait-for-network-service-to-appear/

which addresses http://bugs.python.org/issue5293

Essentially, the recipe performs it's own timeout, since timeouts over 20 seconds appear to be ignored with socket, as there's another shorter timeout that kicks in.